# Redirecting to MS Login page from Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have protected my SPA from APIM. I tried OAuth2 / OpenID Connect/Identity at APIM to check if the caller is authenticated. If caller is not authenticated, i want to redirect him to MS Login Page (Azure AD).
I can see the popup in Developer portal but when calling from SPA from browser, i am only getting 401, Unauthorized message as response.
Please suggest how to redirect to MS Login Page directly from APIM.

OAuth2/Open ID Connect/ Identity available at APIM.
validate-jwt policy in inbound call.